# Yii authentificate и session

Tags: framework, yii

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла такая проблема, есть сессия записанная в средствами

```
Yii::app()->session->add("key", $value);
```

Проблема: сессию что-то уничтожает.

Пояснение: Сразу после аутентификации пользователя вызываю ексепшен

```
throw new \CHttpException(404, "sadasdasd");
```

затем комментирую эксепшн и обновляю страницу, а сессии то уже нема.... Складывается ощущение что сессию уничтожает именно класс CHttpException

Вопрос: Что может быть?

**UPD 1 Пояснение:**

Сессия которая теряется НИКАК не связана с WebUser. Это самая обычная сессия созданная средствами YII. 
На самом деле, есть регистрация в 5 шагов, на каждом шаге инфа пицется в мемкеш, и имя обьекта мемкеш как раз и хранится в сессии. Так вот, вот идем мы 4 шага как неавторизованные и пишем все в мемкеш. На 5 шаге, нам предлагают авторизоваться, мы вводим логин и пароль. и авторизуем пользователя. Дальше два пути:

1. Если при размещении введенной на предыдущих шагах инфой проблем не возникло то все ок
2. Если вылетел Эксепшен, то при попытке нажать кнопку назад в браузере или просто обновить страницу выводится сообщение что сессия умерла (сам проверяю наличие сессии)

Так вот сейчас я этот эксепшен сам эмулирую:

```
            //throw new \CHttpException(404, "sadasdasd-123"); --> певый эксепшен
            if(\app\services\UserService::loginUser($email, $pass)){
                throw new \CHttpException(404, "sadasdasd");  --> второй эксепшен
```

Еще большее пояснение,

1. "Первый эксепшен" сначала вызываем потом коментим и обновляем страницу - сессия на месте
2. "Второй эксепшен" сначала вызываем потом коментим и обновляем страницу - сессия утеряна

Сама UserService::loginUser

```
public static function loginUser($clEmail, $clPass)
{
    $userForm = new \app\forms\UserLogin();
    $userForm->email = $clEmail;
    $userForm->password = $clPass;
    $userForm->rememberMe = true;
    return $userForm->validate();
}
```

Что происходит в валидации

```
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())  // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
    {
        $identity=new \app\components\UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);
        $identity->authenticate();

        switch($identity->errorCode)
        {
            case \app\components\UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
                \Yii::app()->user->login($identity,$duration);//die();
                break;
            case \app\components\UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                $this->addError("email", 'Неверный логин или пароль');
                break;
            case \app\components\UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID:
                $this->addError("password", 'Неверный логин или пароль');
                break;
            case \app\components\UserIdentity::ERROR_UNKNOWN_IDENTITY:
                $this->addError("status", 'Неверный логин или пароль');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс UserIdentity

```
class UserIdentity extends \CUserIdentity {
    // Будем хранить id.
    protected $_id;

    // Данный метод вызывается один раз при аутентификации пользователя.
    public function authenticate(){
        $user = \app\models\User::model()->find('LOWER(email)=?', array(strtolower($this->username)));
        if(($user===null) || ($this->password !== $user->password) || $user->is_activated != 1) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else {
            $this->_id = $user->id;

            $this->username = $user->username;
            $this->setState('roles', $user->role);
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

И для большего уточнения класс WebUser

```
class WebUser extends \CWebUser
{
    private $_model = null;

    /**
     * User class name
     * @var string
     */
    public $userClass;

    function getRole()
    {
        if($user = $this->getModel()){
            // в таблице User есть поле role
            return $user->role;
        }
    }

    public function init()
    {
        if ($this->userClass !== null && isset($this->__id)) {

            try {
                $authManager = \Yii::app()->authManager;
            }
            catch (\Exception $e)  {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                \Yii::app()->controller->widget('app.widgets.alert.AlertWidget',
                    array('type' => 'error', 'close' => false, 'html'=> $error)
                );
            }
        }

        parent::init();
    }

    protected function changeIdentity($id,$name,$states)
    {
        \Yii::app()->getSession()->regenerateID(true); // true, false - пробовал
        $this->setId($id);
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->loadIdentityStates($states);
    }

    public function checkAccess($operation, $params=array())
    {
        if (empty($this->id)) {
            // Not identified => no rights
            return false;
        }

        $role = $this->getState("roles"); //var_dump($role); die();
        if ($role === 'USER_ADMIN') {
            return true; // admin role has access to everything
        }
        // allow access if the operation request is the current user's role
        return ($operation === $role);
    }
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: что браузер показывает? она меняется или что там происходит?

Comment: А что он может показывать :( Объект исчезает и все. Такое ощущение что что то вызывает unset или YIi обертку remove. Но я все перелопатил....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем свою проблему я решил. Я просто запутался в именах обьекта для авторизованного и неавторизованного пользователя.

Answer (score 3):

> Сразу после аутентификации пользователя вызываю ексепшен

При аутентификации сессия пересоздается, поэтому про старую можно забыть.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#changeIdentity-detail

```
protected function changeIdentity($id,$name,$states)
{
    Yii::app()->getSession()->regenerateID(true); // true - флаг удаления
    $this->setId($id);
    $this->setName($name);
    $this->loadIdentityStates($states);
}
```

Чтобы сохранить состояния, сделайте прослойку для пользователя (отнаследованную от CWebUser) и подредактируйте метод `login`, в котором вся сессия будет просто пробрасываться в новую.

**Не используйте прямой доступ к сессии**. Вам нужны `Yii::app()->user->setState()` для хранения постоянных значений и `Yii::app()->user->setFlash()` для хранения временных.

И вообще в Yii 1 отвратительно сделан переход между аутентифицированным и неаутентифицированным пользователем, при переходе, как правило, не получается сохранить информацию.

upd.

> Сессия которая теряется НИКАК не связана с WebUser.

Сессия вообще в принципе одна на пользователя, как она может быть не связана?

Answer (score 0):

вы всмысле в Браузере хотите увидеть переменную сессии с ключом key? или где вы смотрите что после обновления страницы сессии уже нема?